# unable to find the index of element in the code and is always returning -1

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
 let index = this.List.findIndex((a:any)=> 
      {
        a.NAME == result.NAME
      }
      )
```

> Here index is always returning -1 though element is present in the
> List

Comment: can you please post the list? and the `result` object

Comment: Could you be elaborate in terms of the code that you are facing problem with ? Maybe then, it would be easier to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return something:

```
let index = this.List.findIndex((a:any)=> 
      {
       return a.NAME == result.NAME
      }
      )
```

Otherwise its `undefined` wich is `-1`